# Safe to install from daily build PPA?

Tags: ppa, unity-dash

I have the dash blur bug which appears to be common to users of 13.04 with integrated intel graphics. https://bugs.launchpad.net/nux/+bug/1087534

In that bug report people suggest upgrading libnux-4.0.0 from the daily build PPA. I tried this and it fixes the problem. Is this a safe thing to do though or should I wait until the update is released to the main repository? I'm new to Ubuntu so have no idea how long that takes.

Answer (score 1):

The daily build PPA will continue to built and ship Unity daily builds. So while you will get your fix, you'll also get more updates over time, some of which might fix things, but might not be caught by QA.

In your case I would enable the PPA, do an upgrade, then turn off/remove the PPA and then when the updates catch up in the normal channel you'll be good to go moving forward.

Comment: Jorge, thanks so much for the help. This is actually what I had done - just added the ppa, updated the package, then removed the ppa. Good to have that confirmed by someone who knows what they are talking about!